# Does anyone know what this error means in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm new to Unity (and to coding, and to Stack Exchange, so please go easy on me here). I got this error while I was working on a tutorial for Unity (this video, to be exact). Can someone explain what this error is saying? It's not causing any major problems (at least not any that I know of) but I'm trying to learn and understand how this stuff works and I figured I should also learn how this site works as well, since I'll probably be spending a lot of time here in the upcoming months.

Here's the error:

> Assets\Scripts\Movement.cs(3,7): warning CS0105: The using directive for 'UnityEngine' appeared previously in this namespace

Does anyone know what this means?

Comment: That means you have `using UnityEngine;` in two places in the file. Remove one.

Comment: For one it's a `warning` **not** an _"error"_.

Answer (score 0):

This alert probably mean **you've been using 2 times the same namespace**, and in this case **UnityEngine**. Your code may looks like this :

```
using UnityEngine;   
using UnityEngine;

public class YourClass 
{
//code
}
```

To resolve this, delete one of the two first lines :)